# How to use entity class which extends another class in a Room?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-room

I tried searching everything but i didn't find any solution. One question is similar but no one has answered it properly. Moving to the question, I have a class which has room entity annotation and the same class extends another class (which is Library class). Now when i run the project I get an errors like **Error:Cannot find getter for field.** Library's super class making issue here as it works when i remove it. Please tell me how can i make room work with subclass as entity extending super class. Thank you for your time.

```
    @Entity(tableName = "event")
public class EventDetails extends ParentEntity implements Parcelable{

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    int id;

    String name;
    Calendar startDay = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar endDay = Calendar.getInstance();

public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Calendar getStartDay() {
        return startDay;
    }

    public void setStartDay(Calendar startDay) {
        this.startDay = startDay;
    }

    public Calendar getEndDay() {
        return endDay;
    }

    public void setEndDay(Calendar endDay) {
        this.endDay = endDay;
    }

public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}



public class ParentEntity {
    private Calendar mDay;


    public Calendar getmDay() {
        return mDay;
    }

    public void setmDay(Calendar mDay) {
        this.mDay = mDay;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just extending from another class seems to be no problem for an Entity in my sample app. Please provide more details

Comment: Hi @0x0nosugar, super class has few fields which are private. Because of these, it is throwing an error.

Comment: I added a private field with getter and setter to the super class - still no problem. Do the private fields in your super class *have* getters (and setters) which are named correctly?

Comment: Yes the names are proper as i have generated them using alt+insert shortcut. Can we force room to only consider subclass which is entity and not it's super class?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that your super class is in a library not in the module itself? (Sorry but I can't verify that immediately.) What happens if you first create a class in the module which extends from "the super class"  and then you let your entity extend from the middle class?

Comment: I tried replacing library's super class with my own super class. And i have added private fields in my own super class. In this case also i get an error, but when i make those fields public it does not throw that error. And if i make 3 level inheritance, still problem persists.

Comment: Well I'd like to help you but for this I need you to provide some code (the two classes). You don't need to share the "real" classes as long as I can use your snippets to reproduce the issue

Comment: I have edited question and added code. Please check.

Comment: Both classes in same module, parent class not as entity: only issue is with all the Calendar fields because one needs a TypeConverter for them. I'll change them to `long` and then I'll set up the parent class in a library module

Comment: I have already set DateTypeConverter in roomdatabase class. It's not the issue with typeConverter as it doesn't throw error when i make mDay field as public in parent class.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't have your database class, I'm just patching this into some small project I'm working on ;-)  BTW *now* I finally have your error " Cannot find getter for field". With the parent class still in the same module. Good. I'll get back to you if I find anything useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be mainly a naming problem: after changing the field name from *mDay* to just *day* and renaming the setter/ getter accordingly, everything compiles.

It looks like the method names which Android Studio generates from *mDay* are not the ones which Room is looking for.

Since you are in a position to use different field names in the parent class, this looks like the best solution.

If it is not possible to change the library, it is especially not possible to mark fields in the library class with `Ignore`, so one can't fix the problem by inserting an intermediate class into the inheritance hierarchy. (I tried using a Constructor for `EventDetails` with the private field as argument but this too did not work)

So in this case I think your best option would be not to try to extend from the library class (but maybe from some "surrogate parent" class) and to bridge the gap to the library class with the help of some factory class.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. Now i won't inherit that library class. Instead i will try to use my own class everywhere and just convert my class to library compatible class only where it is required. But there might be some way to force room to only consider sub class as an entity.

Comment: @TechHelper - if you find out how to do it, please write an answer to this question and accept it. (I'm sure you know you can always change the accepted answer, also for example if someone else knows how to make Room "ignore" the parent class)